# jenkins execute shell on a specific agent/node

Tags: jenkins

I have to execute a shell on specific agent/node in jenkins. I tried to do it in pipeline and it works but not sure how to do it in shell job.

Below thing is working in pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'N1' }
}
```

Could not get anything to pick a specific agent while running a shell project. I need shell project to execute some shell commands, it always pick master agent.

Answer (score 3):

You can put node{} in steps, such as

```
stage('Run Shell Script on Special Node') {
  steps {
    node('SpecialNodeLabel') {
      script {
        sh "ls -l"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I want a shell job, in pipeline we can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the job there is an option `Restrict where this project can be run` there we can specify the `label` of an agent/node